# Special character check, if statement not working. Java

Tags: java, if-statement, special-characters

For starters, i am quite new to java, so im not sure if there is a simpler way to do this. I am currently creating a password checker. I have the majority of the code running smoothly, except for my Special Character Check.

My code checks work for length, and whether or not there is a number, however it does not for my special character check. I currently have the if statement set up to where if the one of the characters in the string is not a letter, digit, or space, to have specialCharCheck = true. else, keep it as false.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project5_Part1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pass;
        String confirm;
        boolean parameters;
        
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Please enter password : ");
        pass = in.nextLine();
        
        System.out.print("Please re-enter the password to confirm : ");
        confirm = in.nextLine();
        
        parameters = isValid(pass);
        
        while (!pass.equals(confirm) || (!parameters)) 
        {
            System.out.println("The password is invalid");
            
            System.out.print("Please enter the password again : ");
            pass = in.nextLine();
            
            System.out.print("Please re-enter the password to confirm : ");
            confirm = in.nextLine();
            
            parameters = isValid(pass);

        }
        if (isValid(pass)) 
        {
            System.out.println("The password is valid");
        }
    }

    public static boolean isValid(String pass) {
        boolean numberCheck = false;
        boolean specialCharCheck = false;

        if (pass.length() < 8) {
            return false;
        } else {

            for (int i = 0; i < pass.length(); i++) 
            {
                if(Character.isDigit(pass.charAt(i))) 
                {
                    numberCheck = true;
                }
                
                if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(i) && !Character.isSpaceChar(i))
                {
                    specialCharCheck = true;
                    //System.out.println("Test");
                }
                else 
                {
                    specialCharCheck = false;
                }

                
            }
            return (numberCheck && specialCharCheck);

        }
    }
}
```

am i missing a simple error? I know there is another way to do this, but i felt it looked more efficient to do it this way. And the logic made sense to me.

Comment: In the loop, it could set it to true, then set it to false again on the next character. You need it to be true if ANY of the characters are special, currently it tests if the last one is.

Comment: I think it's all right if you just remove the else.

Comment: Cleaning up your code could help quite a bit. You don't need `else`; the `return false` just exits the method, and you're finished. Using standard Java code style (`{` on the same line as the opening statement) will also help make your code easier to read. (Good job on the `return a && b` statement.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Character.isLetterOrDigit(char)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/character-isletterordigit-in-java-with-examples/) expects a character as an argument but instead you are passing it an 'int i'. You need to have,

```
if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(pass.charAt(i)) && !Character.isSpaceChar(pass.charAt(i)))
                {
                    specialCharCheck = true;
                    //System.out.println("Test");
                }
                else 
                {
                    specialCharCheck = false;
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here there is a solution with while:

```
    public static boolean isValid(String pass) {
        boolean numberCheck = false;
        boolean specialCharCheck = false;

        if (pass.length() < 8) {
            return false;
        } else {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < pass.length() && (!numberCheck || !specialCharCheck)) {
                if (!numberCheck && Character.isDigit(pass.charAt(i))) {
                    numberCheck = true;
                }
                if (!specialCharCheck && !Character.isLetterOrDigit(i) && !Character.isSpaceChar(i)) {
                    specialCharCheck = true;
                }
                i++;
            }
            return (numberCheck && specialCharCheck);

        }
    }
```